# Adjust standard errors for within correlation

Tags: correlation, standard-error, robust

I am trying to replicate a table and in one of the notes it's written that **'standard errors are adjusted to account for the within-analyst correlation of the observations'** I am running my regressions in Matlab and obtaining normal SEs. I have been searching how to adpat my SEs to this specific situation and what's the meaning of it but I have not been successful. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, it simply means that within-analyst cluster correlation should be included when applying the regression model. Try GEE.